# Oracle SQL - Absurdly expensive update statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have this statement:

```
update new_table t2
set t2.creation_date_utc =
(select creation_date from old_table t1 where t2.id = t1.id)
where exists
(select 1 from old_table t1 where t2.id = t1.id);
```

The cost according to the explain plan is 150959919. The explain plan shows some full table access for a total cost of like 3000, and then the update has that basically infinite cost. It indeed seems to go on forever if run.

FYI, these tables have no more than 300k rows each.

In addition, this query.

```
select 
(select creation_date from old_table t1 where t2.id = t1.id)
from new_table t2;
```

finishes basically instantly.

What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 3):

if you have an update statement in the format that you mentioned, then it implies that the id field is unique across the old_table (otherwise the first inner query would have raised error returning multiple values for update when in fact, only one value can be processed). So, you can modify your first query to be(removing the where clause since it is redundant) :-

```
update new_table t2
set t2.creation_date_utc =
(select creation_date from old_table t1 where t2.id = t1.id);
```

it might be possible that the above query will still take a long time owing to full table scans. So, you have two options :-

1. apply an index to the old_table table on the id field using the following command.

   ```
   Create index index_name on old_table(id);
   ```
2. modify your update query to the following (untested) :-

   ```
   update new_table t2
   set t2.creation_date_utc=
   (select creation_date from old_table t1 where t2.id=t1.id and rownum=1);
   ```

The rownum=1 should instruct oracle not to do any more searching as soon as the first match is found in old_table.

I would recommend the first approach though.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have an index on old_table.id and nested loop joins are very expensive.  An index on old_table(id, creation_date) would be best.

Comment: Getting a more efficient join between the tables, using the MERGE that user1395 suggests, would probably be better in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use merge statement? I've found it to be more efficient in similar cases.

```
merge into new_table t2
using old_table t1 
on (t2.id = t1.id)
when matched then
    update set t2.creation_date_utc = t1.creation_date;
```

Comment: +1: The merge is likely to be faster because if either of the tables is large then the join between them will be implemented as a hash outer join.

Answer (score 0):

This may be faster and equivalent:

```
update new_table t2
set t2.creation_date_utc =
(select creation_date from old_table t1 where t2.id = t1.id)
where t2.id in
(select id from old_table t1);
```